# Why is it that when connecting to MongoDB, Node.js driver version 3.0 or later does not work, but version 2.2.12 or later works?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I try to connect to MongoDB using Node.js driver `3.0` or later, I get an error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv ENODATA_mongodb._tcp.nodeapi-qxd1n.mongo.net at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19).

[image: Refer here for error message]

But when I use Node.js driver `2.2.12`, my database connected successfully. I have no idea why that worked so can someone please explain why this is the case? Thanks!

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a DNS error.  Are you using the same connection string for both?

Comment: I was just following tutorials on MERN stack but when I tried it using the same steps, it would not work. Not unless I change the driver to 2.2.12 or later.

Comment: What connection string are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js driver version 2.2.12 does not support the DNS seedlist connection string format, i.e. `mongodb+srv://`, while the 3.0 driver does.

The error message suggest that with the 3.0 driver you are using a connection string similar to

```
mongodb+srv://user:password@nodeapi-qxd1n.mongodb.net/database
```

In order to use this, the driver needs to first look up the SRV and TXT DNS records.  These look like this:

```
% dig srv _mongodb._tcp.nodeapi-qxd1n.mongodb.net

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_mongodb._tcp.nodeapi-qxd1n.mongodb.net. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 nodeapi-shard-00-00-qxd1n.mongodb.net.
_mongodb._tcp.nodeapi-qxd1n.mongodb.net. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 nodeapi-shard-00-01-qxd1n.mongodb.net.
_mongodb._tcp.nodeapi-qxd1n.mongodb.net. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 nodeapi-shard-00-02-qxd1n.mongodb.net.

% dig txt nodeapi-qxd1n.mongodb.net

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nodeapi-qxd1n.mongodb.net. 60   IN  TXT "authSource=admin&replicaSet=NodeAPI-shard-0"
```

The driver uses that information to construct a standard connection string like

> mongodb://user:password@nodeapi-shard-00-00-qxd1n.mongodb.net:27017,nodeapi-shard-00-01-qxd1n.mongodb.net:27017,nodeapi-shard-00-01-qxd1n.mongodb.net/database?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=NodeAPI-shard-0

Which should be pretty close to the connection string you are using with the 2.2.12 driver.

The 3.0 driver is failing because your DNS resolve is not responding to the request for the SRV record.

In order to connect with the newer driver, either fix the DNS problem, or use the standard `mongodb://` connection string instead of the `mongodb+srv://` one.