# "MongoDB SRV: DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up server: "":No records found for given DNS query." Robo3t with mongodb SRV

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, mongodb-compass

So, I am getting an error when trying to setup Robo 3T with MongoDB Compass. I don't know why, but here is the error:

"MongoDB SRV: DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up server: "":No records found for given DNS query."

Comment: Are you able to verify that DNS resolution works for the cluster/hostnames?

Comment: @Joe well, I provided it localhost 27017 and I checked and it works on my network.

Comment: "localhost" is not resolved using DNS.  If you are using a mongodb+srv connection string, robo3t will need to be able to reach a DNS server to lookup the SRV and TXT records.

Comment: @Joe how would I do this?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61309409/2282634) shows checking the DNS records using dig.